# NPM Cookie Library doesn't parse Forwarded HTTP header with repeating value correctly

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, npm, http-headers

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded) the `Forwarded` header can have repeating values:

`Forwarded: for=192.0.2.43, for=198.51.100.17`

`Forwarded: for=192.0.2.43, for="[2001:db8:cafe::17]"`

But whenever I use `npm cookie` [(link)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) to parse the header value I get an incorrect value:

```
const cookie = require('cookie');
...
...
console.log(cookie.parse(req.headers.forwarded));
```

Input:

Header key: `Forwarded`

Header value: `for=192.0.2.43, for=198.51.100.17`

Output:

This prints the value `{ for: '192.0.2.43, for=198.51.100.17' }`.

But the correct output should be an array: `{ for: ["192.0.2.43", "198.51.100.17"] }`

I've tried multiple cookie parsing libraries and they can't seem to correctly parse a repeating value. So which library should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with a for each loop to iterate over the headers but I'm still perplexed why this is even necessary.

```
    if (req.headers.forwarded) {
        for (let current of req.headers.forwarded.split(",")) {
            if (cookie.parse(current)["for"]) {
                ip = ip + cookie.parse(current)["for"] + ", "
            }
        }

        if (ip.endsWith(", ")) {
            ip = ip.substring(0, ip.length -2);
        }
    }
```